# Spyder console value different than in the Editor

Tags: python, console, spyder

For a work/study project I have been transitioning from JupiterLab and NOtebook to Spyder, to take advantage of Spyder's included debugger (missing in the other 2 IDE).

While running my very first few lines of code as a tryout, i noticed the code in the console displays some parts that are different from what I wrote in the editor.

Specifically, I try to slice a test List as L_f = L[:k]
why the console executes/displays L_f = L[:k**+1**] ? where is that "+1" coming from?

[Spyder console vs editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bP0l4.png)

Answer (score -1):

no worries, solved with ChatGPT. Spyder default folded some code, compiler was looking different than Editor because in the latter 2 rows were actually folded.